# Android: Log.w() error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm importing the Log library:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

And then trying to use it with:

```
Log.w("myApp", "no network");
```

But I end up getting back `error: <identifier> expected`

[image]

Studio sees the Log object but w is in red.

[image]

Comment: That's because you are writing this code not in a Method, but just somewhere in the class. You can't do that in Java. Are you trying to execute some code in a static context? Then you need to wrap it in a `static { ... }` block.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to **call a method** from the class declaration block (body). Move the `Log.w("myApp", "no network");` line to **any** other method, for example `onCreate()` since you're in an Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w("myApp", "no network");
}
```

See the [Java reference on classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html) for more explanation.